# What is the differrence between these functions?

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, char

I found this code in The C Answer Book.

```
int readline(char s[], int lim) {
    int i,c,j=0;
    for(i=0; (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i) {
        if(i<lim-2) {
            s[j]=c;
            ++j;
        }
    }
    if(c=='\n') {
        s[j]=c;
        ++j;
        ++i;
    }
    s[j]='\0';
    return i;
}
```

I wrote my version :

```
int readline(char line[], int lim) {
    int c, i;
    for(i=0; (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i) {
        if(i<lim-2) {
            line[i]=c;
        }
    }
    if(c=='\n') {
        line[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i]='\0';
    return  i;
}
```

I have used only one variable '`i`' as counter but the original version has used two variable '`i`' and '`j`' as counters.
What is the difference between the two?

Please tell me how do they differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second version of the function leaves part of `line` uninitialised and risks writing the final '\n', '\0' beyond the end of the `line` buffer in cases where the initial loop continues beyond `i<lim-2`

Answer (score 3):

If the user inputs more than `lim-2` characters, the first version works correctly, and the second writes past the end of `line`:

```
if(c=='\n') {
    line[i]=c;  <<=== here
    ++i;
}
line[i]='\0';   <<=== and here
```

This doesn't mean you actually need two variables. You can use one, but you must cap it after the loop. Do whatever you think makes the code is easier to read.

Comment: How do I 'cap' the variable?

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167: See if it's greater than the max value and, if it is, set it to that max value.